# Do while loop comparing Strings

Tags: java, do-while

I'm trying to do a "do while" loop with a nested if statement. I'm trying to compare two possible values for a String variable "word". If !word.equals "deeppan or thin" do something, else do something. But its not liking me using the or || comparator .. Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
 do {
        word = scan.next();
        if ( !word.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan" || "thin" ) ) {
            System.out.print("Sorry you must specify a Deeppan or thin base, try again: ");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while ( true );
```

Comment: You misunderstand the `||` operator.

Comment: *"Any suggestions would be welcome."*  Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: Programming isn't like making sentences: One would say: *Foo doesn't equal X or Y*. While the Java compiler only understands: *Foo doesn't equal X and Foo doesn't equal Y*.

Answer (score 6):

`equalsIgnoreCase` takes a single string argument, not a logical expression. You can combine them with `||` or `&&` though:

```
if (!word.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan") && !word.equalsIgnoreCase("thin" ))
```

Comment: Actually he's not passing more than one argument.. Also I think the `!` should be outside, refer to De-Morgan laws.

Comment: This is wrong. Your boolean logic is not correct: `if (!((word.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("thin")))){` is more like it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it like this:

```
if (!word.equalsIgnoreCase("Deeppan") && !word.equalsIgnoreCase("thin")) {
```

Think about the || which i switched to &&, because the if should only be true, if the value is not the first AND not the second one!

Comment: Why downvoting? All answers of you are wrong with the logical OR, aren't they?

Comment: You got my +1 dude :)

Comment: @Downvoter have you ever heard of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)? In short `!(a | b) == !a & !b`.

Comment: For the fans of OR logic, `if (!(word.equalsIgnoreCase("Deeppan") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("thin"))) {`

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong, that's not how you use the boolean `||` operator, and anyway the logic is incorrect:

```
if (!word.equalsIgnoreCase("Deeppan" || "thin"))
```

It should be like this, comparison-operator-comparison, and notice the correct way to state the comparison for the effect you want to achieve:

```
if (!(word.equalsIgnoreCase("Deeppan") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("thin")))
```

Or equivalently, using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (and easier to read and understand, IMHO):

```
if (!word.equalsIgnoreCase("Deeppan") && !word.equalsIgnoreCase("thin"))
```

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I don't think so... how should it be, then?

Comment: Well, yeah, I see. You are applying right, but you started wrong by saying that what he wants is `(!x || !y)`, instead of `(!x && !y)`.

Comment: It seems that OP is trying to achieve `!(word.equalsIgnoreCase("Deeppan") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("thin"))` which should be `!word.equalsIgnoreCase("Deeppan") && !word.equalsIgnoreCase("thin")`

Comment: Change it with `||` instead of `&&`. A word can not be equal to both "deeppan" and "thin". Instead you want the condition to be "not equal to (deeppan or thin)"

Comment: You're right guys, I didn't stop to think if the logic in the question was correct in the first place. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues going on.  First:

```
 "Deeppan" || "thin"
```

is attempting to use the boolean "OR" operator to compare two strings.  The "OR" operator can only compare boolean results and returns a boolean that is the result of the comparison:

```
      System.currentTimeMillis() == 123455667 || object.equals(this) // both sides are boolean results. 
      true || false  // returns 'false'
```

But let's pretend for a second that `"Deeppan" || "thin"` is OK (remember, it isn't) and the compiler knows that you want to compare the two strings.  It still leaves the issue that the OR operator returns a boolean result (true or false), which you are then attempting to pass into the method `equalsIgnoreCase` on the `word` variable.  `equalsIgnoreCase` takes a `String` argument, not a boolean.  This is the second compilation issue.  As has been pointed out, what you need is to check for the conditions separately and OR the result to get the final boolean

```
if("Deeppan".equalsIgnoreCase(word) || "thin".equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
("Deeppan" || "thin")
```

is a boolean expression. equalisIgnoreCase takes a string. Therefore you need to make two seperate calls and OR the (boolean) results

Comment: Downvoted because it's not any kind of expression. It's illegal syntax to apply the || operator to a String.